# Using MS ReportViewer with MFC

Tags: reporting-services, mfc, visual-studio-2005, reportviewer

I support a legacy MFC C++ application (VS2005) and I want to call some SSRS reports (MS Reporting Services).  I was hoping to use the MS Report Viewer control, but it only works with .Net.  I’ve come up with some ideas, but I keep thinking that I’m working against some conventional knowledge.  I’m hoping to get a second opinion.

We already have a report server setup (remote server processing).  It would be really nice to call reports directly from this MFC application (i.e. show summary report for a customer, etc).  Right now, we are currently just calling Internet Explorer directly with parameter(s) in the URL.  It’s simple, it works, but it’s rather limiting.  For example, I can’t setup printer options.

I’ll mention our project does not compile with the /clr option – we use a few 3rd-party libraries and between those and others we get way too many linking errors.  It’s just not feasible to try to get it working with this project.

I came up with an idea of creating a simple c# application that wraps the ReportViewer, and control it via a few command line options (server, report name).  However, this doesn’t help too much with parameters – I’d have to come up with some way of sending the parameters and then our wrapper program would have to parse them out, etc.

I also thought about creating a dll and calling it from the MFC, but then I keep thinking that I’ll have the same problem with the parameters again.

It would be really nice if there was a MFC version of the Report Viewer, but any searching I’ve done online turns up nothing.  It took me a while just to figure out everything I needed to make the proper calls from my sample c# program.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: can you use a browser control, then pass in the URL to the report?

Comment: Kate - thanks for posting!  Isn't the browser control pretty much the same thing as calling IE directly?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to just stick with calling Internet Explorer directly for now.  In case anyone is wondering how to call IE directly, just read it it's path from the registry into a string and add "/iexplore.exe " to the end.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\IEXPLORE.EXE
```

At that location, read the string "Path"